# fill and submit form using javascript from console

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my form:

```
 <form id="myForm">
        <input id="htmlString" type="text" name="htmlField" ><br>
        <input type="Submit" value="Submit" >
      </form>
```

And need to fill it from console.
just to use it in my app, 
Will inject javascript with data to local html file.

I tried to make the form without a submit button like so:

```
<body>

    <form id="myForm">
        <input id="htmlString" type="text" name="htmlField" ><br>
    </form> 

    <script>
        htmlString.oninput = function(){
         ///do some stuff 
        }

</script>

</body>
```

Expecting that :

```
document.getElementById('htmlString').value="moo" ;
```

It automatically submit the form, because here `oninput` used.
But it just stayed filled with inputs and not proceed further.

Tried with other solution:

```
form = document.getElementById("myForm")
form.submit()
```

But it just refreshed the page and not submitted the form.

The need is just one filed without else, and inject my string to it with javascript to run functions embedded in the html.

Answer (score 2):

Try making the input button hidden.

```
<body>

    <form id="myForm">
        <input id="htmlString" type="text" name="htmlField" ><br>
        <input type="Submit" value="Submit" style="display: none" >
    </form>
    <button onclick="simulateConsole()">Try it</button>

    <script>
        htmlString.oninput = function(){
          if(this.value === "moo") {
             myForm.submit();
          }
        }

        // This event will be triggered even if you use console
        htmlString.onsubmit = function(){
          if(this.value === "moo") {
           // do something onSubmit
          }
        }

        function simulateConsole() {
          // you can simulate this in console
          htmlString.value = "moo";
          myForm.submit();
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: work only when typed with keyboard but not when i inject the value from console

Comment: You can't trigger that event from console. If you permit me, let me edit my answer to do a similar behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply an `action` to the form, otherwise it will just reload the page.

See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form